# jQuery modal window removes elements from my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

jQuery, when i use it to create a modal window which contains form elemets, 
it takes out those elements when i submit the form.

example of the form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/system/article/add/" class="from" method="post"> 

    <label for="article_title" class="required">Title:</label> 

    <input class="formfield" id="article_title" name="article_title" value="" type="text"> 

    <label for="url" class="required">Url:</label> 

    <input class="formfield" id="url" name="url" value="" type="text"> 

    <div id="add_photo" style="width: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content"  title="Add Photo"> 
        <label for="photo_title" class="optional">Photo title:</label> 
        <input class="formfield" id="photo_title" name="photo_title" value="" type="text">
        <label for="photot" class="optional">Photo thumb:</label> 
        <input type="file" name="photot" id="photot" class="formfield">
        <label for="photo_checkbox" class="optional">Include lighbox?</label> 
        <input name="photo_checkbox" value="0" type="hidden"> 
        <input class="checkbox" id="photo_checkbox" name="photo_checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox"> 
        <label for="photo_big" class="optional">Photo:</label> 
        <input type="file" name="photo_big" id="photo_big" class="formfield"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

exaple of JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_photo").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

So what i nocited during the inspetion via firebug, is that jquery actually removes my form elements within #add_photo and puts them outside the form in DOM, so even tough in html the modal dialog is within my form, in DOM it isn't ....

An this is the reason why i'm having the issue!

Have anyone encountered simmilar problem?

Any solution?! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your issue.  I duplicated your problem with the jQuery UI dialog, so it's probably something wrong with the code there.  You might want to submit a bug report to the jQuery team about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just had the same problem. I solved it by adding another

```
<div id="beforesubmit" style="display:none"></div>
```

at the end (but inside) of the form and then you have to add this to jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("#add_photo").prependTo("#beforesubmit");
});
```

This will make sure that before the form is submit your dialog div will be put back in between the form tags. Thanks to *arnorhs* I came to this solution.

Cheers!

Comment: Works like a charm!

Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time! :)

Comment: I could have tried this on my own for ages and wouldn't have come up with this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The form needs to be inside the div. That's how it is in all the Dialog examples. Not sure how you're going to do that with the title and url inputs not being on the dialog. Couldn't you put them on it too?

This wouldn't have the problem:

```
<div id="add_photo" style="width: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content"  title="Add Photo"> 
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/system/article/add/" class="from" method="post"> 
    <label for="article_title" class="required">Title:</label> 
    <input class="formfield" id="article_title" name="article_title" value="" type="text"> 

    <label for="url" class="required">Url:</label> 
    <input class="formfield" id="url" name="url" value="" type="text"> 

    <label for="photo_title" class="optional">Photo title:</label> 
    <input class="formfield" id="photo_title" name="photo_title" value="" type="text">
    <label for="photot" class="optional">Photo thumb:</label> 
    <input type="file" name="photot" id="photot" class="formfield">
    <label for="photo_checkbox" class="optional">Include lighbox?</label> 
    <input name="photo_checkbox" value="0" type="hidden"> 
    <input class="checkbox" id="photo_checkbox" name="photo_checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox"> 
    <label for="photo_big" class="optional">Photo:</label> 
    <input type="file" name="photo_big" id="photo_big" class="formfield"> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i came to a point where i also need this alternative for ajax uploads, of course, jquery removes form tags even when i use it like that!

Comment: but what if your dialog is only part of the form submission

Comment: @oo copy the inputs in the dialog to hidden inputs in the form when the dialog is closed

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what dialog box plugin you're using, but I would suspect that the dialog box plugin is pulling the DIV out of the form and placing it into the body of the page, so It can bring the box in front of the page, outside of the form element.

So to rephrase, in order for the dialog box plugin to make your dialog appear in front of all the content on your page, it needs to remove it from whatever element it is sitting in, no matter if it's a form or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://mytechworld.officeacuity.com/?p=280) describes how to solve your problem:

> You’ll see that the content we had mid-way through our page has been marked up with additional classes and, most importantly, placed at the bottom of the page immediately before the closing tag. Why is this important? Because it also means that any ASP.Net controls you place within this dialog will also appear at the bottom of the page, outside of the page’s tag. This means you won’t be able to get a handle to them on postback.
>
> What’s the solution?  Well, there are two options:
>
> 1. Move the elements back to the form, and manually submit when the button is clicked
> 2. Clone the elements when you create the dialog, then clone the values back, trigger click on the original button (or, if you only have one or two values to post back, simply assign the values to an ASP.Net hidden field control).

Answer (score 1):

From http://blog.coreycoogan.com/2010/12/01/jquerys-dialog-and-form-problems/

Tie it to the form by doing `$("mydialog").parent().appendTo($("form:first"))`.

Note that you have to this call after you already called `$("mydialog").dialog()`

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366741/jqueryui-dialog-window-not-inside-my-div-placed-under-body-how-to-keep-inside), jQuery dialog has a field `appendTo`, that can be used to configure where to put your dialog (div-wise) on initialization.

This seems to be the least ninja-workaround version to tackle the problem.