# ASP.NET MVC: Changing visibility of container disrupts model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a field on my model that is shown on the page like this:

```
<label id="someId">@Model.TextProperty</label>
```

The TextProperty is shown a second time to the page:

```
<div id="hiddenEditForm" style="display: none;">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.TextProperty, new
    {
         @Id = "textPropertyValue"
    })
</div>
```

When submitting the form without touching the `hiddenEditForm`, the Controller receives the original value of TextProperty, no problem there.

However if the form is submitted after `$("#hiddenEditForm").dialog()` (jQuery UI Dialog), the TextProperty on the Model in the controller is empty and the validation fails. It looks like it is explicitly coupled to the jQuery plugin as doing a `$("#hiddenEditForm").show()` does not break the binding.

What's happening here? How can I retain my TextProperty in the controller?

Comment: I misread the question when I answered. If I understand correctly now, you are not receiving the the value on the server when the form is submitted with `display:block` on #hiddenEditForm? And you do get the value if it has `display:none`?

Comment: The page is rendered with div style `display:none`. There is a javascript eventhandler to show the div. Once the div has `display:block` the value is cleared, no matter what happens afterwards. (ie if I hide the div again after it has been displayed, the value in the model remains empty upon form.submit)

Comment: Is the value cleared only on the server, or in the DOM also? Which browser are you using? Have you inspected the posted values with Fiddler or similar? Does it happen in all browsers?

Comment: DOM is ok. The behavior seems to be browser independent (Occurs on both IE and Chrome). Fiddler didn't reveal anything new (first time use though). I figured out it is due the `jQuery UI Dialog`, once I replace the `.dialog()` call with a simple `.show()` things work again as they are supposed to.

Comment: Are you submitting while the dialog is visible, or after you have dismissed it? What does the DOM look like for this element, i.e. is the text box or a parent container hidden?

Comment: Once I do `.dialog`, the container becomes visible (and thus also the textarea). The TextProperty is empty after submitting even if I haven't closed the dialog yet (it is a non blocking dialog). I guess jQuery Dialog does some nasty stuff that makes ASP.NET MVC forget about the textarea even though the properties on the TextArea are unaffected. I think I'm just going to remove the .dialog altogether. Lots of bugs to be fixed, but only so much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has a good discussion of jQuery dialog: [jQuery modal window removes elements from my form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567637/jquery-modal-window-removes-elements-from-my-form).

I have a vague recollection of running into that problem previously.